# c++: указание функции как параметр для другой функции: реализация своей лямбда-функции

Tags: c++, лямбда-выражение

Подскажите как на c++11 можно реализовать следующий функционал:

1) у меня есть функция фильтрации данных

`typedef bool(*filteredFunc)(const CPacketData&);`

которую я буду использовать для обработки входных данных

2) есть структура, содержащая параметры обработки данных (входные условия, выходные данные)

```
struct CStatisticsData
{
    // служебная информация
    filteredFunc                    m_filteredFunc;

    // статистика
    CStatistics                     m_output;

    CStatisticsData(const filteredFunc filteredFunc);
};
```

3) данные обрабатываются разными способами, поэтому и входные параметры и выходные данные разные, но всё хранится в одном векторе

```
typedef std::vector<CStatisticsData> data_t;
```

который я предварительно заполняю следующим образом:

```
data_t allData;
allData.push(CStatisticsData(myFunc1));
allData.push(CStatisticsData(myFunc2));
allData.push(CStatisticsData(myFunc3));
```

а сами функции `myFunc1`, `myFunc2`, `myFunc3` описываю выше

**Вопрос:**

поскольку функции маленькие, то хотелось бы для наглядности размещать их сразу в инициализации, как в JS:

```
data_t allData;
allData.push(CStatisticsData(function(params){
    return (params.name == 'x');
}));
```

Подскажите как это правильно сделать? Как я понимаю это по сути лямбда-функции, но они наверное по другому задаются и используются чем обычные функции в качестве параметров?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
typedef std::function<bool(const CPacketData&)> filteredFunc;
...
data_t allData;
// Простая лямбда
allData.push(CStatisticsData([](const CPacketData& params){
    return (params.name == 'x');
}));

//Лямбда с внешними параметрами
bool externalFlag = readFromSomewhere();
allData.push(CStatisticsData([externalFlag](const CPacketData& params){
    return externalFlag ? (params.name == 'x') : false;
}));

// Обычные функции
allData.push(CStatisticsData(myFunc3));
allData.push(CStatisticsData(myFunc3)); 
allData.push(CStatisticsData(myFunc3));
```

Comment: ffk, а вместо лямбда выражения я обычную функцию подставить могу?

Comment: @Zhihar, да, можете

Answer (score 1):

Если ваши функции-обработчики не захватывают внешних переменных (пустая capture), то у вас уже все готово и ничего больше делать или менять не надо. Ваш

```
typedef bool(*filteredFunc)(const CPacketData&);
```

уже прекрасно совместим с лямбдами с пустым захватом. Т.е. сразу пишите

```
data_t allData;
allData.push([](const CPacketData &params) { return params.name == 'x'; });
```

Другое дело, если вам вдруг понадобятся лямбды с захватом. Но на самом деле вам они не должны понадобиться. Ваша `CPacketData`, по идее, и должна служить "захватом", реализованным вручную. Но если захват таки понадобится, то наиболее простым способом будет переход на `std::function<>`.